# what happens to electron after beta minus decay

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, atoms

In the beta minus decay, electron is emitted from the nucleus. It depends on the previous nuclei(that was before beta decay) how much energy emitted electron will have.

After this event, Internal bremsstrahlung could happen, where electron could be slowed down which would cause the photon emission.

on chatgpt, I read the following:

> The probability of a high-energy beta particle interacting with the
> electromagnetic field of the nucleus is higher because it can
> penetrate deeper into the region surrounding the nucleus where the
> field is strongest

I don't understand this why low-energy beta particle wouldn't be able to do the same as high-energy. I'm also curious when Internal bremsstrahlung would NOT happen in beta decay and where does the emitted electron go ? could it be captured by the atom or it will leave the atom ?

I'd appreciate the thorough explanation of what things happen actually. (Only interested in beta minus)

Comment: -1 for quoting artificial stupidity.

Comment: I agree, so it's stupidity right ? I never trust it but I thought now what if it told me the truth. so can I remove that part from the question ?

Comment: Yeah. Maybe paraphrase if you ever needed to mention it. I heard some issue about license for reusing this "content" on top of its general unreliability.

Comment: chatGPT is not an authetic source of information.

Comment: Despite the poor reference cited, the question is legitimate and deserves an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [NuclearPower.com](https://www.nuclear-power.com/nuclear-power/reactor-physics/interaction-radiation-matter/interaction-beta-radiation/):

"[B]elow 1 MeV... the energy loss due to bremsstrahlung is very small. Radiation loss starts to become important only at particle energies well above the minimum ionization energy. At relativistic energies, the ratio of loss rate by bremsstrahlung to loss rate by ionization is approximately proportional to the product of the particle’s kinetic energy and the atomic number of the absorber."

As for the final resting place of the electron, it depends on the structure of the material in which it finally slows to thermal speed. For example, in crystalline solids, such as alkali halides, [F-center defects](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230705217_Basic_properties_of_the_F-type_centers_in_halides_oxides_and_perovskites) can be produced, coloring the crystal. [An F center](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/F-center) is a type of crystallographic defect in which an anionic vacancy in a crystal lattice is occupied by one or more unpaired electrons. See halide salts being [colorized with a spark coil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xSVgykaPNs).

In electrically conductive media, the electrons can flow, effectively creating an [electrostatic atomic battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_battery)  (which should be  *cell*, rather than *battery*, if you have just one) or [betavoltaic device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betavoltaic_device).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, emitted electron can either attach to the orbital or even leave the atom, right ?

Comment: Likely, they have too much energy to stay in the emitting atom's vicinity, leaving it with a net positive charge... which would eventually be equalized in a conductor. There *are* isomeric transition/internal conversion radionuclides that rearrange the nucleus and emit only γ rays, staying neutral (unless they self-photoionize). BTW, you might remove the ChatGPT reference to improve the question.